# Let $\mu_n \gt 0$, for all $n \in N$. Also let $\lim{\sqrt[n]{u_n}}=\mu$. Prove that $\lim{\sqrt[n]{(n+1)u_{n+1}}}=\mu$

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, limits

The problem says the following:

Let $\mu_n \gt 0$, for all $n \in N$. Also let $\lim{\sqrt[n]{u_n}}=\mu$. Prove that $\lim{\sqrt[n]{(n+1)u_{n+1}}}=\mu$

To be honest I don't even know how to begin solving this. What I have attempted so far is to let $\mu=0$, then for $\epsilon \gt 0$ there exists an arbitrary value M in the natural numbers such that $|u_n^{1/n}| \lt \epsilon$. That is everything I have written. I don't know if this is even correct or where I should go from here.

Comment: A loose intuition for you to formalize:
(u_n*(n+1))^(1/n) = (u_n)^(1/n) * (n+1)^(1/n)
The factor on the right goes to 1

Answer (score 4):

Let $a_n = \sqrt[n]{u_n}$. Then
$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} a_n = \mu = \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} a_{n+1}.$$
But
$$\sqrt[n]{(n+1)u_{n+1}}=((n+1)u_{n+1})^{\frac{1}{n}} =(n+1)^{\frac{1}{n}}\cdot (\left( u_{n+1} \right)^{\frac{1}{n+1}} )^{\frac{n+1}{n}} = (n+1)^{\frac{1}{n}}\cdot (a_{n+1} )^{\frac{n+1}{n}}.$$
We can separately calculate

1.
$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} (n+1)^{\frac{1}{n}} = \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} ((n+1)^{\frac{1}{n+1}})^{\frac{n+1}{n}} = \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} e^{\frac{n+1}{n} \cdot \ln ( (n+1)^{\frac{1}{n+1}} )} = e^{1 \cdot 0} = 1,$$
since $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} n^{\frac{1}{n}}= 1$ and since $\ln t$, $e^t$ are continious functions.

2.
$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}(a_{n+1} )^{\frac{n+1}{n}} =\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}e^{\frac{n+1}{n}\ln(a_{n+1})} = e^{1\cdot \ln \mu} =\mu,$$
since $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} a_{n+1}= \mu$ and since $\ln t$, $e^t$ are continious functions.

Hence,
$$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{(n+1)u_{n+1}} = \mu. $$